# Purpose of adjust out screw on circuit breaker cover

Tags: circuit-breaker

What is the purpose of adjust out screw on circuit breaker cover.  The reason opening was showing is I haven’t put blank back in place.There is one at top and bottom in center of cover. [image][image]

[image]

Comment: If I had to guess (not being able to see inside), I'd say that they adjust the breaker mount with respect to the cover to allow for imperfect depth. More modern panels have the adjustment built into the cover instead.

Comment: Right now, the center metal piece bows out some. If I adjust the screws, should it correct this?

Comment: Bottom right, Square D breaker.  I bet it's a Homeline [which is an alien breaker](https://www.schneider-electric.us/en/faqs/FA129931/) -- Square D forbids their use in non-Homeline panels, as does Eaton.  It's probably not a classified breaker *for* BRyant panels; Square D seems opposed to the very concept of classified breakers. *Same thing with the Murray breaker in the top right*.  Also third from the bottom left, note the fake handle-tie; replace with a listed handle-tie or 2-pole breaker. Just above that double-check the oddball breakers.